# sending json data as POST request via .ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am unable to send data by "POST" request using .ajax method. 
This script shows the existing data from the database and then inputs the additional data by 
1) First deleting the existing rows relating to that id(Send via GET request) and 2)INSERT new rows as reflected by the data sent through JSON.

Below is my Ajax Call

```
        <script src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>

            var collabModel = function(collab) {
                var self = this;
                self.collab= ko.observableArray(collab);
             //To add empty row into the table
                self.addcollab = function() {
                    self.collab.push({
                      Name: "",
                       Lastname: ""
                    });
                };




 self.save = function(form) {
 var loc_id=<?php echo $loc;?>;
   var data_1_1=ko.toJSON(self.collab);

                      $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url:'update_collab_info.php?loc_id='+loc_id,
                           // dataType: 'json',
                            data:data_1_1,
                            processData: false, 
                            timeout:2000,
                                success:function(collab){
                                    alert("This looks like"+data_1_1);
                                  location.href="www/"
                                }
                          });
             };
            };

        var data_from_database=<?php echo json_encode($result);?>; //This is to display any existing rows of information if present from the database

        var viewModel = new collabModel(data_from_database);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

                ===========================PHP SCRIPT(update_collab_info.php)==================
                    <?php
                $data_1=$_POST['data_1_1'];
                $loc_id=$_GET['loc_id'];
                $data_2=json_decode(stripslashes($data_1));

                foreach($data_2 as $row){
                //MYSQL query PDO PREPARE statement 
    //insert ($loc_id, $row['name'],$row['lastname'])
                 }
```

Basically, foreach statement insert multiples rows of fields into mysql where $loc_id remains the same for all of them. ($loc_id is foreign key).
I am not able to get the post data into the PHP script. I do get the alert showing the json data but somehow it is not interpreted by the script. The script is able to respond to the GET variable sent via URL. I am able to delete mysql query which responds to the get request but somehow I get the empty array from the POST data sent as json.

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log(data_1_1);` prior to the AJAX call?

Comment: Nothing shows up in console.log(data_1_1);

Comment: `var data_1_1=ko.toJSON(self.collab);` is not working. Take a look at it, come back to us after that, telling us the result of your thorough research. Before asking here, read [**Stack Overflow Question Checklist**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I am still very new to javascript so please bear with me.I checked Chrome Inspect Element and the console does not seem to point any errors.

Comment: Ok, In my code, I am calling var data_1_1=ko.toJSON(self.collab)  inside the save function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the data as `$_POST["data_1_1"]`, you'll have to send it as a post var rather than as the request body.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update_collab_info.php?loc_id=' + loc_id,
    data: { data_1_1:data_1_1 },
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function (collab) {
        alert("This looks like" + data_1_1);
        location.href = "www/"
    }
});
```

Comment: That does not work but do you think the get parameter in the URL is the problem?

Comment: If it is, it's a php problem not a javascript problem. Sending url params along with post params isn't an issue.

Comment: It was actually a PHP problem in the end because I did not include "true" argument in json_decode($variable,true). Anyways, your suggestion seems spot on. Thanks Kevin.